# How to transform bitmap using matrix and Bitmap.createBitmap()

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, imageview

How to transfom bitmap using matrix ?

matrix.setValues(values);

float[] values = new float[9];

values = {scaleX,skewY,translateX,
skewY,scaleY,translateY,
0,0,1};

Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.width(), bmp.height(), matrix, true);

using these way the bitmaps is only scaled,it is not translated to appropriate x,y